# For a Chrome extension, can it control other extensions like turning them off?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a project where I need to see the page I'm working on without any extension injected code messing up what I see. I want to know if I can create, or if there is currently, an extension that disables all other extensions for xyz page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, extensions can only disable other extensions entirely by using [chrome.management.setEnabled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-setEnabled) API. It's like the on/off switch in chrome://extensions page.

The only way to exclude a certain site from being affected by all or some extensions is to add [`ExtensionSettings` policy](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=ExtensionSettings) with `runtime_blocked_hosts` that contains that site. Note that the entire site is disabled, not just a single URL. Example: `{"*": {"runtime_blocked_hosts": ["*://lastpass.com"]}}`

A simple workaround for your use case may be to open that page in an incognito window or even in a new browser profile without extensions: click your avatar icon in the toolbar to access the profile tools where you can create and then open a new profile.