# Exclude matching a certain URL in host_permission section in manifest.json

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have provided <all_urls> host permission to my extension. But I need to exclude a specific URL.

Below is my manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Chrome DevTool",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "author": "ABC",
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
  ],
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "incognito":"split",
 
}
```

Comment: There's no such feature. The only workaround is for the user of your extension to [add a policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63643533).

Comment: Thankyou for your response @wOxxOm. I have posted another question related Chrome extension, Could you please have a look at it as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75920593/set-origin-header-in-chrome-extension-for-get-request